# Output data is not full

Tags: c#, .net, process

I need some help. I have a external app (test.exe with some dll files). In cmd i have run command like this: `test.exe parmeters` and get a lot of data with some needed info.

I have write app which execute this external app and output is not fully as I exec it with cmd. It's just some firstly lines. I don't mind whats wrong. Please help

```
using(var process = new Process {
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        FileName = orPath,
        Arguments = parmeters.ToString(),
    }
}) {
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
    string result = "";
    string standard_output;
    while ((standard_output = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null) {
        if (standard_output.Contains("xx"))
            result = standard_output.Substring(standard_output.Length - 15);
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is not entirely clear, can you try to rephrase your question please? What output is not fully and what are you expecting? What is all in `argBuilder`?

Answer (score 0):

Without a concise-but-complete code example that reliably demonstrates the problem, it's hard to say for sure. But it doesn't surprise me that if you try to consume StandardOutput *after* you have already called `WaitForExit()`, that not all of the output has been buffered and is available.

Maybe try this instead:

```
        process.Start();
        string result = "";
        string standard_output;
        while ((standard_output = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine())
                                != null)
        {
            if (standard_output.Contains("xx"))
                result = standard_output.Substring(
                       standard_output.Length - 15);
        }
```

Note that I've simply removed the call to `WaitForExit()`. Reading the StandardOutput TextReader until it returns null will have the same effect as waiting for the end of the process, assuming a normal process (i.e. where the stdout doesn't get closed until the process exits).